# proper subgroups $G-H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ a proper subgroup then $G=<G-H>$.

I do not know how to prove this problem, if $H$ is a proper subgroup then H is not G, but how generates G from $G-H$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All we need is that also $H\subseteq \langle G-H\rangle$. 
So given $h\in H$, pick any $g\in G-H$ (which is possible because $H$ is proper). Then $hg^{-1}\notin H$ and so $h=hg^{-1}\cdot g\in \langle G-H\rangle$.

Comment: why you have to see that $H \subseteq <G-H>$?

Answer (score 2):

This follows also from the fact that a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see that this implies my fact?

Comment: Note that $G=H \cup (G-H)$ as sets, whence certainly $G=H \cup \langle G-H \rangle$ as groups. Since $G-H$ is not empty, $\langle G-H \rangle$ cannot be proper and must be the whole group $G$.